New Stock Entry - Add Get Items From Purchase Receipt in frappe (ERPNext) not working with TypeError (positional argument)
I have a use case where we need to select items from Purchase Receipt while creating a new stock entry.
I added the following code in stock_entry.js from the example of Purchase Order>Get Items From>Material Request:
Reference: ERPNext Github
if (frm.doc.docstatus === 0) {
            frm.add_custom_button(
                __("Purchase Receipt"),
                function () {
                    erpnext.utils.map_current_doc({
                        method: "erpnext.stock.doctype.purchase_receipt.purchase_receipt.make_stock_entry",
                        source_doctype: "Purchase Receipt",
                        target: frm,
                        date_field: "posting_date",
                        setters: {
                            supplier: frm.doc.supplier || undefined,
                        },
                        get_query_filters: {
                            docstatus: 1,
                            status: ["not in", ["Closed", "Completed", "Return Issued"]],
                            company: frm.doc.company,
                            is_return: 0,
                        },
                        allow_child_item_selection: true,
                        child_fieldname: "items",
                        child_columns: ["item_code", "qty", "custom_order_no"]
                    });
                },
                __("Get Items From")
            );

It is showing the pop-up and enabling item selection but when I click on 'Get Items', I get this error:

TypeError: make_stock_entry() takes from 1 to 2 positional arguments but 3 were given

Screenshot
Details - app versions:
{
    "ecommerce_integrations": "1.17.0",
    "erpnext": "15.10.6",
    "erpnext_telegram_integration": "1.2.0",
    "frappe": "15.11.0",
    "hrms": "16.0.0-dev",
    "payments": "0.0.1",
}

Route:

    Form/Stock Entry/new-stock-entry-atjbituihp

Traceback

    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "apps/frappe/frappe/app.py", line 110, in application
        response = frappe.api.handle(request)
      File "apps/frappe/frappe/api/__init__.py", line 49, in handle
        data = endpoint(**arguments)
      File "apps/frappe/frappe/api/v1.py", line 36, in handle_rpc_call
        return frappe.handler.handle()
      File "apps/frappe/frappe/handler.py", line 49, in handle
        data = execute_cmd(cmd)
      File "apps/frappe/frappe/handler.py", line 85, in execute_cmd
        return frappe.call(method, **frappe.form_dict)
      File "apps/frappe/frappe/__init__.py", line 1682, in call
        return fn(*args, **newargs)
      File "apps/frappe/frappe/utils/typing_validations.py", line 31, in wrapper
        return func(*args, **kwargs)
      File "apps/frappe/frappe/model/mapper.py", line 53, in map_docs
        target_doc = method(*_args)
      File "apps/frappe/frappe/utils/typing_validations.py", line 31, in wrapper
        return func(*args, **kwargs)

> TypeError: make_stock_entry() takes from 1 to 2 positional arguments but 3 were given

Request data

    {
        "type": "POST",
        "args": {
            "method": "erpnext.stock.doctype.purchase_receipt.purchase_receipt.make_stock_entry",
            "source_names": "[\"PR-24-013\"]",
            "target_doc": "{\"docstatus\":0,\"doctype\":\"Stock Entry\",\"name\":\"new-stock-entry-atjbituihp\",\"__islocal\":1,\"__unsaved\":1,\"owner\":\"Administrator\",\"naming_series\":\"\",\"purpose\":\"Material Issue\",\"add_to_transit\":0,\"company\":\"DEMO Company Ltd.\",\"posting_date\":\"2024-04-29\",\"set_posting_time\":0,\"inspection_required\":0,\"apply_putaway_rule\":0,\"from_warehouse\":\"Stores - DPL\",\"to_warehouse\":\"Work In Progress - DPL\",\"items\":[],\"from_bom\":0,\"use_multi_level_bom\":1,\"additional_costs\":[],\"letter_head\":\"Demo Bottom Signature\",\"is_opening\":\"No\",\"is_return\":0,\"expense_account\":\"Stock Adjustment - DPL\",\"total_additional_costs\":0,\"posting_time\":\"22:59:54\",\"address_display\":null,\"purchase_receipt_no\":null,\"supplier_address\":null,\"supplier_name\":null,\"supplier\":null,\"sales_invoice_no\":null,\"delivery_note_no\":null,\"customer_address\":null,\"customer_name\":null,\"customer\":null}",
            "args": "{\"allow_child_item_selection\":1,\"merge_taxes\":0,\"filtered_children\":[\"00f8822ef7\"]}"
        },
        "freeze": true,
        "freeze_message": "Mapping Purchase Receipt ...",
        "headers": {},
        "error_handlers": {},
        "url": "/api/method/frappe.model.mapper.map_docs",
        "request_id": null
    }

Response data

    {
        "exception": "TypeError: make_stock_entry() takes from 1 to 2 positional arguments but 3 were given",
        "exc_type": "TypeError"
    }

I will appreciate any guidelines to resolve the issue. 

Thanks.







